# what is Dracula's complete life history in folklore?

Tags: dracula

can anyone direct me a good site where I can read about dracula(the fiction vampire one not the real life one) his entire history when he was young and how he became a vampire up to his death in the original stoker book? I would really appreciate it!I know dracula untold movie sheds some light, but I mean before dracula untold came out of course

Comment: have you considered reading the book?

Comment: There are a few comments by Dracula and by Van Helsing.  In the book there was a Dracula family of hereditary counts who once ruled from a castle near the border of Transylvania with Bukovina.  Dr. Van Helsing believed the vampire Dracula was the most famous of the Draculas, who had become voivode or governor/prince (of Transylvania?) and fought against the Turks.   If this famous historic Dracula was contemporary with his namesake Vlad III "Dracula", Prince of Wallachia, he would have lived about from 1428/31 to 1476/77, and be over 400 years old at the time of the novel.

Comment: This question has a couple of quotes from Van Helsing with a little biographical information: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83269/what-were-dracula-s-true-motives-in-going-to-england?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The character Dracula was invented by Bram Stoker. Everything that can be considered canon about Dracula is in the book Dracula. The book says very little about his past. Even his past as a vampire isn't mentioned much. It's known he fought Ottomans at some point but I think that's about all that he mentions about his mortal life.

Though as a side note, it is worth commenting that Dracula was based on Vlad the impaler, or Vladimir Drăculea. He is a fascinating historical character and is probably the closest thing to a "canon" past for the fictional character.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out ["The Annotated Dracula" by Leonard Wolf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0517520176). The annotations are extensive and interesting.

Comment: Does it provide additional in-universe backstory, or just BTS sort of stuff about the author and writing of the story?

Comment: I don't have my copy at hand, but I don't think the sort of thing you're looking for exactly exists, although other authors have covered it homage stories. Wolf's book has a lot of detail on the characters, era, that sort of thing.